# Need help deploying angularjs 1.5 application in serverless architecture on AWS

Tags: angularjs

I've an existing web application developed in angularjs 1.5. And now, I'm planning to deploy it in a serverless architecture on AWS.

I've been googling around to get leads on how to achieve this. But, most of the links/tutorials that come up in Google search, suggest using ng-toolkit. However, when I start following those links/tutorials, I realize that those tutorials use angular2.0. These links/tutorials are not helpful, as my angular version is 1.5 and I know, angular2.0 is way different from it's predecessor.

So, my question is -
Is it possible to have my existing angularjs 1.5 application, to be deployed in a serverless architecture on AWS? If yes, can you share some links, that will help me set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have successfully deployed our Angular 1.x web applications to an AWS S3 bucket, and then configure the bucket to support static website hosting.

You will want to give your bucket the same name as the URL of your desired website.  Your bucket contents will need to be public, so be careful with what you push to this bucket.  Should only be your Angular website bits.

You can then go to Route53 and create an alias A record to point to your S3 bucket.  But note that is will only give you http:// support.  To support https://, you will need to create a certificate in AWS CertificateManager and a corresponding AWS CloudFront distribution.  You can source your CloudFront distribution to pull from your S3 bucket, and use the new certificate to support https://.  You will then need to go into Route53 and point your A record to the CloudFront URL.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an angular 1.x application on a serverless architecture is like deploying any static website. You create an AWS S3 bucket, configure it for static website hosting, then set up CloudFront with https (use the CertificateManager to get a free certificate) to point to the public url of the bucket as origin.

Then you can set up Route53 to point your domain to the CloudFront URL. Here is a YouTube-Tutorial describing the whole process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwgB_sIhIko